# google plus crashed when I connect to google plus and share data in android app

Tags: android, google-plus

I have done my Google+ integration in android I am using Kit Kat version for testing 
everything is fine when I login to google plus its successfully login but when i want to share something. google Plus is crashed and the error is give below
I don't understand what's the error meant

```
12-06 17:50:14.827: I/chromium(26490): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
[05:53:30 PM] Asim Habib: 12-06 17:50:14.907: E/qdutils(26490): FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO failed
```